# What is the equivalent command of “pg_escape_string” for Oracle in PHP?

Tags: string, oracle, escaping, pg

I am importing data from excel to postgresql database and I fetch each column value using pg_escape_string function in php. However, I have to do the same operation for oracle but there is no such command supported for oracle.

Can someone please guide me how to achieve it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that such a function exists in Oracle (at least, I can't remember of any). Though, what you could do is demonstrated below: either use two consecutive single quotes, or `q'[...]'` quoting mechanism (square brackets can be curled, round, ..., as long as they don't appear in the string itself). This is a neat option as it allows you to handle two, three or four single quotes in the same line (yes, that happens, for example when building dynamic SQL; Forms might be a real nightmare here).

OK, here you go:

```
SQL> create table test (col varchar2(30));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (col) values ('This is Scarlett O''Hara');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test (col) values (q'[This is John O'Leary]');

1 row created.

SQL> select * From test;

COL
------------------------------
This is Scarlett O'Hara
This is John O'Leary

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you. 
Kindly look at this code:

"$name = pg_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->getValue());" 

I am fetching data column wise from excel. Can I fetch it like the same way in PHP using any oracle function?

Comment: I'm sorry, I wouldn't know, I don't speak PHP. I was hoping that example I wrote might give you an idea ... Hopefully, someone else will assist.